# Create a pairing query with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this query:

```
       $and: [
        {
          userId: {
            $in: userIds
          }
        },
        {
          promptId: {
            $in: promptIds
          }
        }
      ],
```

but I quickly realized that it was incorrect, since the wrong userId could be paired with the wrong promptId.

Instead I need to do something like this:

```
$or: [
  {
   userId: 'foo1',
   promptId: 'bar1'
  },

  {
   userId: 'foo2',
   promptId: 'bar2'
  },

  {
   userId: 'foo3',
   promptId: 'bar3'
  },
]
```

is that $or query optimal? Is there a better way to write that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to find a document having `userId: foo1` and `promptId: bar1`, you can use db.collection.find() like this

```
db.collection.find({userId: 'foo1',promptId: 'bar1'})
```